# Why in windows I can see folders and device connected to the network that in debian I don't see?

Tags: debian, shared-folders

I was looking for shared folders in the public network of my schoolhouse  and I noticed that a lot of shared directory and devices connected to the network that I can see in Windows don't appear in Debian's list (especially Windows shared folder and smart TVs). Why? What should I do to make them visible?

Answer (score 1):

To view Windows shares in Linux you need to use SAMBA. Further, if the network is using Active Directory to allow people to connect to shares then you need to authenticate against the Domain Controller.

Comment: I have samba. What should I do to see?

Comment: @IlarioVitali read [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html) for further explanation. If you have any questions after that then make a new question here.